# Passing model property to helper function in Razor VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have a the following code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.UserName)
```

I have put this code in the helper function inside my .vbhtml that looks like this:

```
@Helper displayTextBox(modelElement As [WHAT???])
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) modelElement)
End Helper
```

And call my functions like so:

```
displayTextBox(model.UserName)
```

But that that doesn't work, my TextBox name becomes $VB$Local_modelElement if I declare it as `String` or `Object`, and I've tried to declare modelElement in the helper function as `TProperty`, but I got an error saying that "Type 'TProperty' is not defined".

Coincidentally, this works fine, where `ActualModel` is the actual class name that I have for model type:

```
@Helper displayTextBox(modelElement As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of ActualModel, String)))
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelElement)
End Helper

displayTextBox(Function(model) model.UserName)
```

I just want to place that `Function(model)` statement inside the Helper function. Is it even possible? What am I doing wrong?